# Add Authorization role to access an XML(WSDL) file by using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

I have a WSDL and  I want to add permission on it that all people can't see all the methods on it:

```
     <wsdl:types>
    ...
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message>
    ...
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap">
     <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
         <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
         <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn" />
         <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut" />
     </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
        <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    ...
  </wsdl:portType>
```

....

Now I want to restrict access to this part of my WSDL :

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
    <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

it means: I want to CLient-X has this role for seeing  this method but Client-Y doesn't have enough role for seeing this method?

How can I use this issue in .xslt file by using xsl language?

Comment: I think before thinking about XSLT, you need to figure out how you can do this in _WSDL_.  Once you know that, making an XSLT to make the necessary modifications is the next step.

Comment: I want to resrict my clients based on their IP address?

Comment: I think the correct design would be to actually restrict your web-service based on the requesting IP, not just hide the interface from the WSDL.  Even if the caller can't see the method in the WSDL, they can still call it, and this is a security hole. XSLT has no inherent functionality to retrieve the IP of someone making a web request.  If you want to perform logic based on an IP address, you need to pass the IP address in as a parameter, or define an extension function to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In Mule, use `mulexml:context-property` to [pass information](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/XSLT+Transformer#XSLTTransformer-Example) about the user rights to the XSL,
- In the XSL, use [conditional processing primitives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing) to control the output of the `wsdl:operation` elements based on the user rights information.

And of course, rendering the WSDL differently based on user rights is half of the problem: you'll also have to reject unauthorized SOAP requests.